# Capture video without preview

Tags: android

I want to capture video without showing a preview. The android docs here say this is possible, but don't explain how:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video

> Note: It is possible to use MediaRecorder without creating a camera preview first and skip the first few steps of this process. However, since users typically prefer to see a preview before starting a recording, that process is not discussed here.

what are the "first few steps" to skip?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misinterpret the documentation. What it really says (***emphasis*** mine):

> It is possible to use MediaRecorder without creating a camera preview ***first*** and skip the first few steps of this process. However, since users typically prefer to see a preview ***before starting a recording***, that process is not discussed here.

In other words, you can create a preview and immediately start recording. There is no hint that **MediaRecorder** will let you run a hidden recording session.

Moreover, I agree with the document that the added value of not starting preview before starting recording, is negligible.

Comment: So u need a preview?

Comment: @jonney yes, you do. If you winder whether this preview must be visible in the screen, the answer is 'no, but'. Take 'users typically prefer to see a preview' as a strong warning.

Comment: probably the issue I am having on my latest stack flow question. Please have a look and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can just skip step 5 of configuring media recorder given in the above link and preview wont be shown. But user will be interested in viewing its preview.

Comment: If I don't tell mediarecorder the output file, then nothing will get captured at all?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation states it is possible, most of SO answers say otherwise. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694810/android-video-recording-illegalstateexception-on-mediarecorder-start/32787009?noredirect=1#comment53417931_32787009) (and the answers linked in it).

The work around this limitation is to create a 1 x 1 px `SurfaceView` and use it to display the camera preview.

Comment: I wonder if it's the same performance hit as to just put an opaque view on top of the full screen preview view?

Comment: That's a pretty good question. Given this is handled by the native layer, I'd guess the impact is pretty much the same. The preview size (set in the camera parameters) will probably have a bigger effect.

Comment: On many devices, 1x1 preview happens to be a huge performance hit, much worse than 16x16.